# Show UIImageView on rotation fullscreen

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Currently I have a scrollview with some pictures in it. If I rotate the phone to landscape, I want the picture in the scrollview to become large (full screen) so that the entire screen is covered with the image. Rotating it back to portrait should remove the fullscreen image.

What I did so far in my viewDidLoad to detect rotation changes:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleOrientationChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and to handle it:

```
- (void)handleOrientationChange
{
    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
        UIImageView *fullScreenImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [fullScreenImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[PflanzenSingletonClass sharedManager] loadStringFromUserDefaultsForKey:CurrentScrollViewImage]]];
        [fullScreenImage setTag:999];
        [self.view addSubview:fullScreenImage];
    } else
    {
        [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:([[self.view subviews] count] - 1)] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But it's not working as expected (surely my fault).

1. The ImageView is not really fullscreen. I still see the navigation bar
2. Image is not rotated to landscape (is my method called right before the orientation change takes place??)
3. Because of 2. the image is stretched.
4. I would like to have this much smoother with an animation. Starting point is the rect of the scrollview.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle this in ViewController, you may override next methods instead of using notifications:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
```

To make ImageView fullscreen (and to display it over navigation bar) you may add it to keyWindow:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[imageView setFrame:keyWindow.bounds];
[keyWindow addSubview:imageView];
```

**Update.**

Also you can present UIImageView in separate UIViewController presented modally.
In this ViewController implement method

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toOrientation)) {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:];
    }
}
```

Also ensure that your application support both landscape and portrait orientations. It can be edited in summary tab or App-Info.plist. Also it may be specified for certain controlelr by overriding next methods:

for ios6:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

for ios5:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
```

Comment: setting the frame to keywindow wont fill the picture to fullscreen :( I still see the navigation bar

Comment: I think the UIImageView is still on top of my UITableView but behind the NavigationControllerView

Comment: Are you sure you added imageView to keyWindow? if so, try to call [keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

Comment: ups :) forgot to add it to key window. Thats it :) But now how do I remove it from there?

Comment: You can save somewhere link to this view and call -removeFromSuperview, or get from Window's subviews (as you do in your question)

Comment: I added the landscape orientations but method didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is not called. Is that the reason that the images do not turn?

Comment: I tried the methods for iOS5 and 6 but still same effects. First I set the imageView frame then I add the image. After the rotation of the device, the image is rotated as well. When and how should I add the UIImage to the ImageView?